# RTTI: how to get the object pointer of a field?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have a `TRttiProperty` variable named `aRttiProperty`, that points to the property below:

```
Tsubscription = class(TMyObject)
private
  fBilling: TMyObject;
public
  property billing: TMyObject read fBilling; // << aRttiProperty point to this member
end;
```

Now, how can I extract the `fBilling` object pointer from `aRttiProperty`?

I try to do it like this, but it is not working:

```
function Tsubscription.getfBillingObj(const aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty): TMyObject 
begin
  Result := aRttiProperty.GetValue(Self).AsType<TMyObject>;
end;
```

It's returning the parent `TSubscription` object instead of the `fbilling` field object.

Comment: Well that is just overkill, when you can just use `Result := MySubscriptionInstance.Billing;` instead.

Comment: @Remy - My guess would be Loki wants to write to the field.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: If he needs the memory address of the `fBilling` field itself, going through `TRttiProperty` is not the correct way to do that (unless you type-cast it to `TRttiInstanceProperty` and then decode its `PropInfo^.SetProc` value). A better option would be to get the offset of the `fBilling` field within the `Tsubscription` class by using `aRttiType.GetField('fBilling').Offset` (where `aRttiType` represents the `TSubscription` class), and then add that offset to the starting memory address of a `Tsubscription` object.

Comment: There is also `FieldAddress` taking the name of the field and returning a simple pointer, which can be cast to `TMyObject`.

Comment: @UweRaabe: the `TObject.FieldAddress()` method only works for fields that are declared as `published`. In the OP's example, `fBilling` is declared as `private` so `SomeSubscriptionObject.FieldAddress('fBilling')` will return `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you showed in your question is perfectly fine (provided you fix your `Tsubscription` class declaration to include the `getfBillingObj()` method).  The `getfBillingObj()` code you showed returns the correct object pointer, as demonstrated by the following code:

```
uses
  System.Rtti;

type
  TMyObject = class
  public
    Name: string;
    constructor Create(const aName: string);
  end;

  Tsubscription = class(TMyObject)
  private
    fBilling: TMyObject;
  public
    constructor Create(const aName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function getfBillingObj(const aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty): TMyObject;
    property billing: TMyObject read fBilling;
  end;

constructor TMyObject.Create(const aName: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Name := aName;
end;

constructor Tsubscription.Create(const aName: string);
begin
  inherited Create(aName);
  fBilling := TMyObject.Create('bill');
end;

destructor Tsubscription.Destroy;
begin
  fBilling.Free;
end;

function Tsubscription.getfBillingObj(const aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty): TMyObject;
begin
  Result := aRttiProperty.GetValue(Self).AsType<TMyObject>;
end;
```

```
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  sub: Tsubscription;
  bill: TMyObject;
begin
  sub := Tsubscription.Create('sub');
  try
    prop := ctx.GetType(Tsubscription).GetProperty('billing');
    bill := sub.getfBillingObj(prop);
    // bill.Name is 'bill' as expected...
  finally
    sub.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, it is not necessary to use RTTI in this situation since `TSubscription` has direct access to its own internal fields:

```
function TSubscription.getfBillingObj: TMyObject 
begin
  Result := fBilling;
end;
```

But even that is redundant since the `billing` property is public.  Any caller can just use the `billing` property as-is:

```
var
  sub: Tsubscription;
  bill: TMyObject;
begin
  sub := Tsubscription.Create('sub');
  try
    bill := sub.billing;
    // bill.Name is 'bill' as expected...
  finally
    sub.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I didn't realize the code trying to acquire the pointer was in the very class  that has it as its field. Renders RTTI pretty redundant..

Comment: Thanks remy! perfect answer ... i found the bug in my code thanks to your confirmation that aRttiProperty.GetValue(Self).AsType<TMyObject>; is the good way :) in fact i was doing Fbilling := TMyObject(Self); instead of Fbilling := TMyObject.create(Self); .... stupid "visual" mistake :(